# How can i get more RAM for my app in C#?

Tags: memory, io, out-of-memory, ram

I have a program in C#, that needs to utilize 1GB of memory. However I use some adapter code which takes additional RAM. It seems that I can`t allocate more than 400MB at runtime.

Can you point me out in the right direction of optimization?

```
private static void FillHashTable()
{
  precomputed = new Hashtable( (Int32)( 50 * 1000000 ) );

  var htFileNames = Directory.EnumerateFiles( "precomputed_bin" );

  var input = new Byte[40000000];             // 40MB
  var decoded = new UInt32[input.Length/4];   // 40MB

  foreach ( var htFileName in htFileNames )
  {
    try 
    { 
      hStream = new FileStream( htFileName, FileMode.Open ); 
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) 
    {
      if ( hStream == null )
        return;

      hStream.Close();
      Console.WriteLine( e.ToString() ); 
      return; 
    }

    var br = new BinaryReader( hStream );
    input = br.ReadBytes( (int)hStream.Length );

    Buffer.BlockCopy( input, 0, decoded, 0, input.Length );

    foreach ( var n in decoded )
      precomputed.Add( n.GetHashCode(), n );        // 40MB per iter

    // close
    br.Close();
    br.Dispose();
    decoded = null;
    hStream.Close();
    hStream = null;
    GC.Collect();        
  }

  SerializeHashtable();
}
```

So far, only 40% of data could be loaded and I need it all in RAM.

Should I use C++ to avoid indeterminant time of garbage collection? (my top option for now)

Or should I divide input in chunks to reuse them and avoid overhead?

Am I freeing resources incorrectly or GC fails?

Should I somehow inform OS that I need more than 1GB?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If this is Java (you didn't say), then you can start the jvm with the -Xmx parameter specified.

Also, you might reconsider whether or not your app really needs to load all of that into memory at once.

Comment: Thanx, but it`s C# - I added this to my topic now.

This memory is a giant (1GB) hashtable to determine if 6-byte number is prime in O(1) time.

My task is to process a file (which might be large) and find longest sequence of primes.

So, it seems that I really need this 1GB at my hand :(

It`s kinda stange that CLR gives me only 400MB. Or is it Win64 restriction? Doubt it.

Offcourse for big numbers (over 5 billions) I check primality during runtime.

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to tune that in the .NET run-time configuration, but I don't specifically how to do that.  You might check MSDN.

Could you not write the hash table to disk and then load parts of it while you search?  If the table is sorted or indexed on-disk in a way that is optimal for this task, then you could probably hit your complexity goals.